# Trouble understanding the use of "@" within scope, using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently trying to get to grips with angularjs by following the tutorial [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-attribute-binding).

If I have the following controller and directive set up:

```
app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.ctrlFlavor = "orange";
});

app.directive('drink', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            flavor: "@"
        },
        template: '<div>{{flavor}}</div>'
    };
});
```

and the following html:

```
<div ng-app="drinkApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div drink flavor="{{ctrlFlavor}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From what I understand from the tutorial, the ampersand means that any expression put in the *flavor* attribute will be evaluated and the result will be ctrlFlavor function being called and hence "orange" being rendered on the page. However this doesn't happen, "{{flavor}}" is rendered instead as an error is thrown:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$parse/syntax?p0=ctrlFlavor&p1=is%20unex…20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7BctrlFlavor%7D%7D&p4=ctrlFlavor%7D%7D
```

The tutorial also says the "@" means the attribute will be evaluated as a string. In this situation I'd expect "{{ctrlFlavour}}" to be rendered but it seems the controller is being accessed and rendering "orange" instead. Why is this? Have I misunderstood what the "@" sign and "&" do? I'm really very confused..

Thanks

Comment: Your understanding of `@` is correct and the code you posted works. The problem is somewhere else. Can you post a fiddle? Here's your code working... http://jsfiddle.net/Z8jEZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `orange` rendered as the value for the `flavor` attribute is being interpolated as per the `{{ }}`.

If you changed the above to:

`<div drink flavor="ctrlFlavor"></div>`

You would simply get `ctrlFlavor` rendered.

For what it's worth I also found isolate scope to be a bit confusing when starting out.

Also here's a code snippet to helpfully explain further what's happening.  I've added examples for `@`, `&` and `=` for isolate scope.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NMeHya72HDXBu8trTEUK

Comment: Thank you! The examples were very helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

@ allows you to pass the value of an parent attribute to an attribute in a directive's isolate scope.

Note that, by default, flavor maps to the DOM attribute favir. If we wanted to explicitly specify the name of the attribute we wanted to bind to, we could do so:

```
scope:{
    ctrlFlavor: '@flavor'
}
```